# How to initialize k-means

Tags: r, k-means, image-processing

I am working on image processing. I have to apply k-means upon them. But I am confused with the initialization of k-means that either I should use just first frame or all the frames to initialize it. And each frame is row vector with distinct number of rows.
Kindly clear my concept

Comment: It is fast, so I have always used random initialization.  One might do well to use an adaptive variation on Poisson disc initialization.  It likely depends on how naively the data is stored.

Comment: Okay. But I am concerned about the data to be used for initialization of kmeans. As I mentioned,  I am working on image processing and I have to pass frames value (comprised of three attributes) to my kmeans. And I am asking that should I use first frames values for kmean initialization or all the frames values.

Comment: If you are using K means in the images, how are you contriving it? Are you contriving the locations of the pixels as XY? What are the names of your three columns? Is your data discreet as in eight distinct colors, or is it continuous on the domain between zero and one? There are several useful axes to consider here. Also, what are you gonna do when you’re done? Are you using an information criteria to determine the correct number of clusters?

Comment: These three attribute give me background information, optical flow and histogram of optical flow. The data is continuous. Yes I am using information criteria.